# How do I log responses in the correct order using Async code

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I need to create a function that runs a 'getFile' function on each item in an array. The getFile function logs 'File contents of x' x being whatever element is in the array.

Currently, I have a working function that runs the getFile on the array and waits for the final response before logging the results.

However, I now need to log the responses as I receive them in order. For example, if my array is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] currently it logs 'File contents of x' in a random order, so if it was to return the logs, 3 then 4 then 1. As soon as I receive 1, I need to log that, then once I receive 2 logs that and so on.

I will insert my current code below. The problem I'm having is I need to know when the 'empty space' in my array becomes populated so I can log it in real time. Therefore allowing my user to see the result build up rather than just having to wait until all the responses have come back

```
function fetchContentOfFiles(fileNames, testCB) {
  const fileContent = [];
  let counter = 0;

  fileNames.forEach((file, i) => {
    getFile(file, (err, fileName) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else {
        fileContent[i] = fileName;
        counter++
        if (counter === fileNames.length) {
          testCB(null, fileContent)
        };
        console.log(fileContent)
      };
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need them in order? If the first one happens to take the longest, it'll be be the same thing as waiting for all of them. If you want to let the user know that stuff is happening, why not just log each response as it is received?

Comment: Do you want to make the requests in *serial*? That is, wait for index 0 to finish before sending out index 1's request? (note that this will make things slower, but will make the requests go in order)

Comment: "*The problem I'm having is I need to know when the 'empty space' in my array becomes populated so I can log it in real time.*" that doesn't sound like a problem - you already know what came back when the callback fires. So I'm not sure why you claim it's a problem. "*Therefore allowing my user to see the result build up rather than just having to wait until all the responses have come back*" I don't see how that goal necessitates processing in order. If the responses come back 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 5 just visualise that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes that's exactly what I want to do. For example if I had an array of thousands of elements, rather than having the user wait till the whole array is populated. I would like to inform them that the contents have been filed as they come through in the correct order. So file index 0's response, then index 1 and so forth.

Comment: If your array has thousands of elements, that'll likely take quite a long time, especially if ping is bad, are you sure? Sounds quite unusual

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes it is unusual and counter-intuitive. However, it's just an 'advanced problem' on an a-sync sprint I've been doing. The previous question was just to wait for all the responses and log them once they're all there (as shown in the code above). Before anyone says anything this is NOT homework, this is purely out of my own curiosity as to how you'd do something like this. I understand this wouldn't be in any way practical as I'm increasing the users wait time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to write this would be to use a `for` loop inside an `async` function. Promisify `getFile` so that it returns a `Promise`, then await it in every iteration of the loop. At the end of the loop, call the callback:

```
const getFileProm = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  getFile(file, (err, fileName) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(fileName);
  });
});

async function fetchContentOfFiles(fileNames, testCB) {
  const fileContent = [];
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
      fileContent.push(
        await getFileProm(fileNames[i])
      );
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors, if you want, maybe call testCB with an error and return?
  }
  testCB(null, fileContent);
}
```

It would probably be even better if `fetchContentOfFiles` was called and handled *as a Promise* rather than with callbacks, and then the errors can be handled in the consumer:

```
async function fetchContentOfFiles(fileNames) {
  const fileContent = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    fileContent.push(
      await getFileProm(fileNames[i])
    );
  }
  return fileContent;
}

fetchContentOfFiles(arr)
  .then((fileContent) => {
    // do stuff with fileContent
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // something went wrong
  });
```

Comment: I had an inkling that I would have to use promise as it was listed as an 'advanced' problem and we haven't covered 'promises' just yet. Thanks for the rapid response!